# Multiple Runnables on one handler, wrong repeat behaviour

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, android-handler

In my android application I need to update different parts of the UI (actually a `Fragment` inside a `ViewPager` on a different time intervals. To do this I've created an `Handler` and 3 `Runnables`. With the `postDelayed(Runnable, delay)` method the Runnables should repeat themselves at scheduled time intervals.
Currently I have 1 runnable that must update a `TextView` every 100 ms, another that update a `ProgressBar` every 1000 ms and another one that checks some stuff every 2000 ms.

I saw the counter and the progress bar incrementing too fast and so I've put some code checking the delay between every call to the `Run()` method and I've discovered that the first runnable is executed every 58 ms and the progressbar's one running every 508 ms.

I've then tried to left only the first Runnable on the Handler (the counter one) and the `Run()` method get called every ~101 ms. So I've hypothized that other Runnables maybe interfer with the Message Queue schedule. I've then created one Handler for every Runnable but in that way the problem persist with 56~58 ms in the first Runnable and 508~510 ms on the second one.

Any suggestion on why this behaviour happen?

Here's part of my code:

```
private static final int TIME_STEP_COUNTER = 100;
private static final int TIME_STEP_PROGRESS = 1000;
private static final int TIME_STEP_DIRECTOR = 2000;

private Handler counterHandler, progressHandler, directorHandler;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // some code here
    directorThread = new DirectorThread(wwp,TIME_STEP_DIRECTOR);

    if(directorHandler == null){
        directorHandler = new Handler();
        directorHandler.post(directorThread);
    }
    startCounting();
}
```

**StartCounting() method**

```
public void startCounting(){

    stdCounterUpdater = new CounterUpdaterThread(textViewCounter,TIME_STEP_COUNTER, increment100ms);
    progressUpdaterThread = new ProgressUpdaterThread(progressBar,TIME_STEP_PROGRESS,textViewPercentage);
    fixerThread = new FixerThread(wwp,TIME_STEP_FIXER);
    if(counterHandler == null){
        counterHandler = new Handler();
    }
    counterHandler.post(stdCounterUpdater);
    if(progressHandler == null){
        progressHandler = new Handler();
    }
    progressHandler.postDelayed(progressBarInitThread, DELAY_INIT_PROGRESS);
    progressHandler.postDelayed(progressUpdaterThread, DELAY_INIT_PROGRESS + INIT_PROGRESS_DURATION);
    counterLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

### Threads

**CounterUpdater**

```
class CounterUpdaterThread implements Runnable{

    public CounterUpdaterThread(TextView counterView, long deltaTime, float increment){
     //Constructor with fields initialization
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        counter  += increment;
        changeCounterText();
        if(counterHandler != null){
            counterHandler.postDelayed(stdCounterUpdater,deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

**ProgressUpdater**

```
class ProgressUpdaterThread implements Runnable{

    public ProgressUpdaterThread(ProgressBar pBar, long deltaTime, TextView percTW){
        //Fields init
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        anim = new ProgressBarAnimation(progressBar, progress, progress + smoothScale);
        progress += smoothScale;
        anim.setDuration(PROGRESS_UPDATE_DURATION);
        progressBar.startAnimation(anim);
        percTW.setText(String.format(Locale.US,"%.1f", progressBar.getProgress()*100f/progressBar.getMax()) + "%");
        if(progressHandler != null){
            progressHandler.postDelayed(progressUpdaterThread,deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

**DirectorThread**

```
class DirectorThread implements Runnable{

    public DirectorThread(WeeklyWorkPeriod wwp, long deltaTime){
    //init
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        if(isStarted){
                //....code.....
                stopCounting();
                isStarted = false;
                //....code.....
            }
        }
        else{
                 // ...code...
                raiseMethod.requestProgressData(ProgressBarFragment.this,fragmentID);
                startCounting();
                isStarted = true;
            }
        }
        if(directorHandler != null){
            directorHandler.postDelayed(directorThread,deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked also these articles and some other question but with no results

[Repeating Tasks](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Repeating-Periodic-Tasks)

[Handler Vs Timer](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.it/2013/12/handler-vs-timer-fixed-period-execution.html)

[Handlers and Loopers](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Managing-Threads-and-Custom-Services#handler-and-loopers)

Comment: run [this](https://pastebin.com/J9zN1XGp) and watch the logcat

Comment: @pskink Nice approach, times seems correct. Tomorrow I'll try changing the code with `postAtTime`. Thanks

Comment: If we use handler.postDelayed(runnableName, 100); statement multiple times with different runnable is this ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem: wasn't about a single handler but about starting new callbacks in the DirectorThread. Just setting in the `onCreateView()` method `isStarted` to `true` solved the problem.

Among the other things I've replaced `postDelayed()` with `postAtTime()` as suggested by *pskink* cause it happens to be more accurate.

Comment: If we use handler.postDelayed(runnableName, 100); statement multiple times with different runnable is this ok ?